# Como ler conteúdo de arquivo binário em Javascript

Tags: javascript, arquivo, binary

Como ler o conteúdo de arquivo binário em Javascript?

Comment: Fernando, poderia dar um exemplo de arquivo?

Comment: Sugiro usares uma biblioteca. Por exemplo: https://github.com/jDataView/jBinary

Comment: De onde vem o arquivo, e o que você quer fazer com ele?

Comment: Com o advento do HTML5, você pode explorar o recurso "File API" e manipular os binários que queres trabalhar por meio de javascript. Segue link sobre o assunto:
[Trabalhando com File API](http://tableless.com.br/file-api-trabalhando-com-arquivos-locais-usando-javascript/) Boa sorte!

Comment: JavaScript web ou NodeJS?

Comment: @Fernando, precisamos de mais informações para podermos ajuda-lo. ex : Qual é o contesto da sua dúvida ? Por você precisa fazer essa leitura ? O Javascript estaria no servidor ou no cliente ? Caso você precise que a sua aplicação Web leia o arquivo você não pode envia-lo para o servidor e ai você o alteraria ?

Answer (score 18):

Depende da origem de onde necessita ler o arquivo se deseja ler da máquina do usuário, você precisará do `File API` combinado com `<input type="file">`.

Ler um arquivo:

```js
function LerArquivo(file, done, fail) {
    var reader = new FileReader;
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        done(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function(evt) {
        fail();
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

var response = document.getElementById("response");

document.getElementById("test").onchange = function() {
    if (this.files.length === 1) {
        LerArquivo(this.files[0], function(resposta) {
             response.value = resposta;
        }, function() {
             response.value = "Falha ao ler o arquivo";
        });
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="test">
<textarea style="width:100%; height: 400px;" id="response"></textarea>
```

Ler múltiplos arquivos:

> note que é necessário adicionar o atributo `multiple` ao `<input>`

```js
function LerArquivo(file, done, fail) {
    var reader = new FileReader;
    var name = file.name;

    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        done(name, evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function(evt) {
        fail(name);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

document.getElementById("test").onchange = function() {
    if (this.files.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0, j = this.files.length; i < j; i++) {
            LerArquivo(this.files[i], function(nome, resposta) {
                console.log(nome, resposta);
            }, function(nome) {
                console.log("Falha ao ler:", nome);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple id="test">
```

Note que é possível ler o arquivo de maneiras diferentes:

- `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()` trás o resultado como [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)
- `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` trás o resultado como como Base64 com Data URI Scheme
- `FileReader.readAsText()` trás o resultado como texto e você deve definir o encoding conforme a necessidade.
- `FileReader.readAsBinaryString()` trás o resultado byte a byte (*Esta em desuso e será removido* então é preferível usar `readAsArrayBuffer` ou `readAsDataURL`)

Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

> Apesar de não ser considerado se referir a isto como parte do HTML5, ainda sim não é correto, HTML5 é uma coisa e APIs Javascript são outra coisa. O HTML5 na verdade consiste de novas tags e funcionalidades no HTML e as novas APIs Javascript interagem com essas novas funcionalidades do Html5.