# Como interpretar conteúdo binário, .dat?

Tags: javascript, binary, interpretador

Preciso interpretar arquivos *.dat*, por exemplo. Suponho que este seja o conteúdo dele:

`³Å¸ÎÔ|`,

sendo que seria equivalente à "Davis" como um texto.

Em JavaScript, usando `XMLHttpRequest` para um arquivo .dat desses deveria dar resposta com o texto "Davis", mas ele não interpreta isso.

Como posso interpretar esse conteúdo complexo com meu código em passos?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como ler conteúdo de arquivo binário em Javascript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64188/).

Comment: @Bacco Embora não haja a resposta relacionada. ENFIM, minha pergunta é sobre interpretação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem jeito sem saber qual codificação foi usada para gerar esse arquivo.

.dat costuma ser usado para dizer que esse é um arquivo binário em um formato que só o programa que o criou entende.

Esse tipo de arquivo vem caindo em desuso em favor de alternativas auto-descritivas, de forma a separar a representação dos dados do programa que usa os dados. Você provavelmente conhece XML e JSON-- eles surgiram para resolver esse tipo de problema.

O jeito agora é você procurar a documentação fornecida por quem está te entregando esses dados para entender como eles estão estruturados antes de prosseguir.

Comment: Eu estava exatamente tentando entender a forma dos dados pelo editor de .dat que estava usando em testes. Se você não tivesse respondido eu não poderia tentar continuar.