# Requisição AJAX falha ao utilizar o protocolo file:/// na origem. Como resolver?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

Estou fazendo um programa bem simples onde preciso ler um arquivo .txt com JavaScript. Não estou usando nenhuma IDE, só criei arquivos .html, .js e .txt em uma pasta.

Para simplificar a pergunta, criei em uma pasta o seguinte código HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Titulo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lerTXT.js"></script>
</body>
```

Encontrei [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file) um código (de 8 anos atrás) que fez sentido. Então criei `lerTXT.js` assim:

```
var rf = new XMLHttpRequest();
rf.open("GET", "exDados.txt", false); // recebo warning por deixar síncrono
rf.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(rf.readyState === 4){
        if(rf.status === 200 || rf.status == 0){
            var texto = rf.responseText;
            alert(texto);
        }
    }
}
rf.send(null);
```

Quando rodo o HTML no Firefox, ele me retorna um erro como:

> Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em file:///C:/Users/arthur/Desktop/projeto/exDados.txt. (Motivo: requisição CORS não é HTTP).

Ou:

> Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/arthur/Desktop/projeto/exDados.txt. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Entendi que isto é para restringir o acesso a endereços diferentes do domínio da aplicação.
Mas no caso é só um arquivo na mesma pasta. Não coloquei em nenhum servidor ou algo assim.

Descobri que antigamente o Firefox e outros navegadores entendiam `file:///` como mesmo domínio, mas agora não mais. Tem algo que eu possa acrescentar no código para que ele ignore o bloqueio de cross-orign? Ou talvez uma nova forma de carregar arquivos?

Sei que tem como usar a tag `<input type="file">` para receber arquivos, mas queria que o Javascript carregasse automaticamente o .txt sem precisar que o usuário o carregue.

Comment: talvez devesse tentar algo mais moderno :) pode usar  `File API`, veja aqui: https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/

Comment: Sim, eu dei uma olhada nesta API e o que encontrei foi sua relação com a tag `<input type="file">`, onde o usuário manualmente carrega o arquivo. Tem como utilizar esta API mas carregando o arquivo de forma automática e sem o bloqueio de cross-orign?

Comment: @ArthurJC Existe mais de um problema em seu código, primeiro o protocolo FILE não opera com XmlHttpRequest, como já mencionei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239475/3635, segundo, você usou o terceiro parametro como FALSE em .open() e depois usou onreadystatechange, o que não faz sentido, pois o false indicará para ser sincrono e não assincrono, logo isso não seria "Ajax", como expliquei em [**AJAX não é uma linguagem de programação. Então o que é?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116177/3635)

Comment: Terceiro, se o objetivo é ler arquivos da máquina do cliente, é preciso usar um `<input type="file">` com a api nativa do JS File, como forneci de exemplo em: [Como ler conteúdo de arquivo binário em Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117499/3635). Se esse não for o caso e você estiver tentando ler um arquivo dentro do projeto, então o problema é que está rodando a página HTML sobre o protocolo file (não falo da parte ajax, me refiro a página toda), alguns detalhes em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/62797/3635

Comment: Foi isso mesmo Guilherme, estava rodando em protocolo FILE. Com sua explicação e a do Luiz Felipe ficou bem mais claro. Agora utilizarei a extensão Web Server for Chrome, assim não precisarei utilizar a tag `<input type="file">`. Obrigado!

Comment: @ArthurJC na verdade input=file é para outra coisa, como expliquei nos comentários, ou o problema é ler um arquivo local, que resolverá de uma forma, ou o problema é ler um arquivo da "aplicação", que nesse caso dispensa o input, a tratativa é tudo no ambiente da aplicação, pois na pergunta não estava claro qual o objetivo, ler arquivos de usuários ou arquivo dentro da aplicação ;) ... Não esqueça do detalhe do sincrono e assincrono, que é outro problema em seu código, que apesar de funcionar ainda sim deveria ser ajustado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está tentando fazer uma requisição XHR (ou *Fetch*, em termos *modernos*). Outras pessoas podem entender como requisição AJAX.

Em resumo, CORS é:

> CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) é um sistema que consiste na transmissão de HTTP headers, que determina se navegadores vão bloquear código JavaScript de acessarem respostas provindas de requisições entre origens.
>
> <sup>[[Fonte]](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/CORS)</sup>

Ou seja, é um conjunto de políticas de segurança implementadas pelos navegadores que determinam se o código JavaScript pode acessar respostas de requisições entre origens (entenda isso como as supracitadas requisições AJAX). Sobre CORS em si, você pode consultar mais em [Qual é o significado de CORS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145490/qual-%C3%A9-o-significado-de-cors)

Entre as políticas (consultar documentação — [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS) e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors)) do CORS, pode-se citar aquela que proíbe que requisições AJAX sejam executadas quando a origem não utiliza o protocolo `http:` ou `https:`. E é esta política que causa o problema detalhado na pergunta.

Note que você não subiu um servidor para realizar a requisição. Você está acessando o arquivo HTML diretamente pelo navegador utilizando o protocolo `file:`.  Naturalmente, portanto, a requisição XHR será bloqueada pela política CORS do navegador, uma vez que não é HTTP  e nem HTTPS.

Você pode consultar o protocolo da origem com este código:

```js
console.log(location.protocol);
```

A documentação dá mais detalhes sobre este erro específico: *[Reason: CORS request not HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp)*.

## Solução

A solução é simples: você deve executar a requisição de modo que a origem esteja em protocolo `http:` ou `https:`. Para isso, em ambiente de desenvolvimento, a solução mais comum é utilizar um servidor local de desenvolvimento.

Se você está imerso no ecossistema Node.js, pode utilizar a CLI [`serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve). Uma outra opção é utilizar uma extensão do editor de texto. No VSCode, a mais comum para esse fim é a [extensão Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer).

Comment: Entendi. Agradeço a explicação bem detalhada! Tive o receio que seria algo assim... Não estou utilizando nenhuma IDE, fiz tudo no Notepad++ mesmo. Gostei de sua sugestão sobre extensão para editor de texto. Procurarei um servidor local então. Encontrei para o Atom (atom live server), mas não para o Notepad++. Você conhece algum?

Comment: Para o Nodepad++ não conheço. :/ Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, você pode aceitá-la, clicando no ícone de check no canto superior esquerdo. :)

Comment: Encontrei a extensão: "Web Server for Chrome". Funcionou super bem! Vou adotá-la de agora em diante.

Comment: Resposta Aceita! Obrigado!